# How do I replace one Bootstrap modal with another modal via a link in the first modal?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

When a user clicks a button on my site, they are prompted to sign up for our service. This prompt appears via a Bootstrap modal. But it's possible that the user will already have an account, in which case I want them to be able to log in. I want to add a "log in" link within the modal that when clicked will close the "sign up" modal and open a new "log in" modal on the same page. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a click event to the login button and trigger two actions. 
1. Target the register modal by its ID and add the toggle option of the modal method to it. This will check the current state (in this case 'opened state') and activate the reverse.
2. Target the login modal and attach the show option of the modal method to it as shown below.

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click', '#id_login_button', function(){
   $('#id-to-register-modal').modal('toggle');
   $('#id-to-login-modal').modal('show');

   return false;
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is helpful.